# Getting datetime when an Azure Event Hub EventData message was created

Tags: azure, datetime, testing, events, event-handling

I've built an Event Hub Listener test facade class to listen for event messages.  I am getting the EventData messages returned successfully, but I only need to look at those for the last 15 minutes.  I have searched online but cannot find if there is a timestamp attached to the message somehow for when it was created.

Does anyone know if this exists?  Perhaps one of the 'Properties' values?

I appreciate timestamps are often not relevant to the running of event hub messages (though they are useful for the testing of them):
[Can a date and time be specified when sending data to Azure event hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646588/can-a-date-and-time-be-specified-when-sending-data-to-azure-event-hub?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But, there has been mentions of adding a timestamp so just wondering if one ever was?
https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/issues/91

Answer (score 1):

Our EventData objects returned by the Event Hub Listener, have a SystemProperties value of 'EnqueuedTimeUtc' so that can be used.